# What is the name of the snake which cause blindess?

Tags: hadith, animals

According to hadith Muhammad (PBUH) asked us to kill the snake with two white lines on it's back.

> Narrated 'Aisha: The Prophet said, "Kill the snake with two white
>   lines on its back, for it blinds the on-looker and causes abortion."
>
> **Sahih Buckari** Book 54, Hadith 527
>
> Narrated Ibn Umar: That he heard the Prophet delivering a sermon on
>   the pulpit saying, "Kill snakes and kill Dhu-at-Tufyatain (i.e. a
>   snake with two white lines on its back) and ALBATROSS (i.e. a snake
>   with short or mutilated tail) for they destroy the sight of one's eyes
>   and bring about abortion." ('Abdullah bin 'Umar further added): Once
>   while I was chasing a snake in order, to kill it, Abu Lubaba called me
>   saying: "Don't kill it," I said. "Allah's Apostle ordered us to kill
>   snakes." He said, "But later on he prohibited the killing of snakes
>   living in the houses." (Az-Zubri said. "Such snakes are called
>   Al-Awamir.")
>   **Sahih Bukhari Book 54, Hadith 518**

What is the name(english) of this snake ?

Is this snake still existing or gone extinct ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a specific type of snake, on of them is called cobra.  It has two white lines that sometimes look like a "U" shape on it's back.

Cobra's usually spit venom into the eyes of its victims.  The venom can blind, handicap, and even cause abortions.

However, there are other types of snakes that have similar effects.

> They are capable of spitting their venom into the eyes of a victim
>   leading to intense pain in the eyes. This may lead to intense
>   conjunctivitis, corneal erosions, complicated by secondary infection,
>   anterior unveitis and sometimes blindness

*[Snakes and Snake Bites](http://apps.who.int/medicinedocs/documents/s16775e/s16775e.pdf)*

You can also read *[Snake Bites During Pregnancy](http://www.supplements.annemergmed.com/PDF/Pregnancy.pdf)*

Allaho Alim

Comment: I dont think it's the Mozambique Cobra . Because the Hadith clearly says snake with two white lines on it's back.

Comment: I have added another hadith which gives more information (arabic name)